# Can I use the Android-Facebook SDK in Processing?

Tags: java, android, facebook, processing

I have an Android sketch in Processing and i was asked to integrate facebook photo uploading to it, the thing is that i have very little time to make this change, so I can't recreate the app in Eclipse. Has anyone ever integrated the android-facebook sdk in Processing? Can it even be done? I have to know quickly so I can tell my clients whether i can do it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could tell, no, it can't be done (yet).